# Slider live changing Wave Packet animation Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, slider, physics

My animation is slow because of the update function which continually calculate a matrix which change only when I move my slider :

```
def evolve(psi0, height, width):
    global psi
    potential = potentialBarrier(height, width)
    tM = timeMatrix(hamiltonian(potential))
    psi = tM.dot(psi0)
    presenceProbability = abs(psi) ** 2
    norm = sum(presenceProbability)
    presenceProbability /= norm
    psi /= norm ** 0.5
    return presenceProbability


def update(frame):
    line.set_ydata(evolve(psi, potentialSlider.val*10, widthSlider.val))
    line2.set_ydata(potentialBarrier(potentialSlider.val, widthSlider.val))
    return

wavePacketAnimation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=5, blit=False)
```

How can I make the update function calculate the new result of my matrix **only** when I move my sliders value and use the previous result when I don't move my sliders ?

I tried to define my matrix global but it didn't work. I've got this so far

```
sliderHasChanged = True
tM = timeMatrix(hamiltonian(potentialBarrierInit))


def evolve(psi0, height, width):
    global tM
    global sliderHasChanged
    if sliderHasChanged:
        potential = potentialBarrier(height * 10, width)
        tM = timeMatrix(hamiltonian(potential))
        sliderHasChanged = False
    global psi 
    psi = tM.dot(psi0)
    presenceProbability = abs(psi) ** 2
    norm = sum(presenceProbability)
    presenceProbability /= norm
    psi /= norm ** 0.5
    return presenceProbability


potentialSlider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
potentialSlider = Slider(potentialSlider_ax, '$V_0$', 0, 1, valinit=0.1)
potentialSlider.label.set_size(15)

widthSlider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
widthSlider = Slider(widthSlider_ax, '$a$', 0, 20, valinit=10.0)
widthSlider.label.set_size(15)


def sliderChange():
    global sliderHasChanged
    sliderHasChanged = True
    return


potentialSlider.on_changed(sliderChange())
widthSlider.on_changed(sliderChange())


def update(frame):
    line.set_ydata(evolve(psi, potentialSlider.val, widthSlider.val))
    line2.set_ydata(potentialBarrier(potentialSlider.val, widthSlider.val))
    return


wavePacketAnimation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=5, blit=False)
wavePacketAnimation.running = True
```

The animation runs well with the initial matrix value but a change in the slider doesn't affect the animation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. Could you add some more detail about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited it, I hope it's clearer !

Comment: what is the slider changing?

Comment: The matrix value, I progressed in my problem and I edited my new code.